# String expression for java class

Tags: java, string, substring

```
String sentence = "Bill has a cow 76786545 54324567 mary@lamb.com";
```

How do i retrieve the `76786545 54324567` w/o using array?

I have tried the following:

```
String[] num = sentence.split("\\s"); 
for (int x=0; x<num.length; x++) { 
   System.out.println(num[x]); 
}
```

Comment: Learn how to use regular expressions to parse strings. That may help you with your problem.

Comment: Im not able to use regular expressions too for this task

Comment: Do you want to separate them? Save it into a string variable? Please update you question with your limitations. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: This is what i have tried. String[] num = sentence.split("\\s");
        for (int x=0; x<num.length; x++)
        {
            System.out.println(num[x]);
        }

Comment: I have embedded your code in the question.

Comment: What is the output from that code?

Comment: if this is an assignment, no need to be "clever". Use a simple combination of indexOf and subString to look for the exact string. http://codingbat.com/doc/java-string-indexof-parsing.html

Answer (score 4):

You can construct a new String and replace all non-digits characters with a space:

```
newStr = newStr.replaceAll("\\D+", " ").trim();
```

`\D` is a regex that matches any character that's not a digit: `[^0-9]`:

```
-> String sentence = "Bill has a cow 76786545 54324567 mary@lamb.com";
-> sentence.replaceAll("\\D+", " ").trim()
|  Expression value is: "76786545 54324567"
```

Comment: this is a clever solution, perhaps include `public static void main(String args[])` so OP can recognize this? maybe also and output?

Comment: @BlakeYarbrough Added an example with OP's string.

Comment: Nice trick. But what will happen if he has some other digits in between those texts, which are not part of that number ?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee they'll be returned as well. The regex can be easily modified to match the exact pattern OP wants (in case there can be such digits).

Comment: Thanks! Say if email is mary12@lamb.com, how do i omit the 12 when i do the replaceAll method so it doesnt print tgt with my "76786545 54324567"

Comment: @nur Do you have a pattern? Or the text can be anything? If you don't have a fixed pattern, the better solution would be splitting the String according to space(s) and for each check if it's a number.